# Checking for undefined variable vs false variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eslint

I'm using ESLint to check my javascript code and I found an warning for "Unexpected use of undefined"

The statement is

```
if (data.items === undefined) {...}
```

Data.items is equal to a JSON object normally, but under some conditions it could just be undefined and I want to take a separate action if that is the case.

To get rid of this warning, is it appropriate to use

```
if (data.items === false) {...}
```

Are these two statements equivalent under these circumstances?

Comment: No, `false` is different than `undefined`. In fact, `false === undefined` will give you `false`.

Comment: It seems you have this rule enabled: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undefined .

Comment: What is the appropriate way to check for an undefined value then?

Comment: See my answer for a couple of options. If you actually want to use `undefined` though, you can just disable the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, they are not equivalent.** For them to be equivalent, `undefined === false` would have to be `true`. However, `===` performs *strict* equality comparison, meaning that values of different data types are never equal. `false` is a value of the *Boolean* data type, `undefined` is the value of the *Undefined* data type. Hence `undefined === true` is `false`.

---

If you want to test for the value `undefined` explicitly without referencing `undefined`, you can use `typeof`:

```
if (typeof data.items === 'undefined')
```

---

If you want to test for the *existence* of the property `items`, you can use the `in` operator or `.hasOwnPropery`:

```
if (!data.hasOwnProperty('items'))
if (!('items' in data))
```

---

If know that the possible values of `data.items` are either `undefined` or an object, you can simply let JavaScript's type conversion work for you and use

```
if (!data.items)
```

If `data.items` is an object (including arrays) `!data.items` will be `false`. If it is `undefined`, it will be `true`.

Comment: Thank you! That definitely clarified some things for me. It was really that I needed to test for the existence of the property.

Comment: Well, testing for existence can be the same as testing for `undefined`, depending on the values the property would have. As I said, if property usually holds an array or object, then `if (!data.items)` will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

People often recommend doing this for checking the existence of a value:

```
if (typeof data.items === "undefined" || data.items === null)
```

It is worth noting that it is exactly the same as a perfectly valid:

```
if (data.items == null)
```

And the only reason that it is problematic are the linter rules created for beginners and imposed on everyone.

What the `== null` does is checking for `null` or `undefined`. Of course your linter will scream at you under the assumption that you cannot be trusted to understand the behavior of `==` and remember two values that the `== null` matches - namely `null` and `undefined`, the two most common values that you often compare your data with.

When the linters started complaining, we had to bloat our code by changing all:

```
if (x == null)
```

to:

```
if (x === null || x === undefined)
```

but apparently it wasn't verbose enough and now we have to write:

```
if (x === null || typeof x === 'undefined')
```

I'm sure that some day people will figure out that it is still too short and an even more correct way will get invented. Until then this is the currently blessed way to test for existence of a value.

By the way, I don't recommend using:

```
if (!x)
```

because it will match not only `null` and `undefined` but also `false`, `0` and the empty string. In fact I am surprised that the linters still allow this construct and haven't forced us to use this yet:

```
if (x === false || x === 0 || x === '' || x === null || typeof x === 'undefined')
```

I'm sure it's just a matter of time, though.

Answer (score 1):

While `if` statements will evaluate the individual values (`false`, `null`, and `undefined`) as falsy, it doesn't hold them to be exactly the same. `null` and `undefined` can be `==` evaluated as true, but `false` is *not* equivalent, and even with `null` and `undefined`, `===` will return false.

**TL;DR**- **No**, they aren't equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Both are `falsy` values, but are not the same. In addition to what Felix Kling has mentioned, if you want to check the *existence* of a variable, I think a fairly safe way to do is how `coffeescript` does it:

`if(typeof data.items === "undefined" || data.items === null)`

---

Also, the way you are currently checking with undefined would try to equate it with an object called undefined. Now modern browsers have made this object immutable and set its initial value to primitive undefined, but I believe there was a time when it was mutable. In that case, if someone were to change the value of undefined (the object) your check would fail! :D